# Display Distances and Azimuths for parcels in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need to extract distances and azimuths (metes and bounds) from shapefile parcels in QGIS. I tried using the "Azimuth and Distance Calculator" plug-in, but all that I get when I run it is "The limit of a patrimonial area must be single part geometry" and then Python error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". The shapefile I am trying to extract Distances and Azimuths for is here: http://honolulu-cchnl.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/parcels-tax

Does anyone know how I can make the plug-in work or an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: create a buffer 0, and check the plugin again...

Comment: The error message implies that some of your parcels are multi-part polygons. Try running the `multipart to single parts` tool.